# EJB+EclipseLink or Spring+Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, ejb

I noticed many projects, that are based on Spring framework use Hibernate for JPA.
But when they base on EJB, they use often EclipseLink.
Is my observation correct?
If yes - why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked on a couple EJB projects and multiple Spring ones that all used Hibernate.

From a Spring perspective one reason that most Spring projects use Hibernate is that Spring has always had extremely good integration with Hibernate and is constantly improved to use the latest Hibernate releases. Using Spring and Hibernate just works!!!